# Existence of Irrational Number that has same $n$ digits of a given Rational Number.

Tags: number-theory, approximation, fractions, continued-fractions

**Problem:** 
Any decimal number $z$ of $n$ digits after decimal point is given.
Does there always exist  an irrational number $q$ (or expression related to irrational number) which has same $n$ digits of $z$  after decimal point?

**Example:** Consider, rational $0.41421356237309504880168872420$ as $z$, then $q=\sqrt2$ since  $\sqrt2$ has same $29$ digits of $z$  after decimal point.

Decimal Point is a point or dot used to separate the whole number part from the fractional part of a number.

Comment: There is a nice thing called *density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$*. And $$0.41421356237309504880168872420\color{red}{\neq}\sqrt{2}$$ *(Very) close to* is not the same as *equal*. $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $q+\frac{1}{10^{200}\sqrt{10}}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ are very close.

Comment: Well, if your example question can take the answer $\sqrt(2)$, then yes; there always exist an irrational number which has same digits as of a rational number after decimal point. You can simply construct the irrational number which has the same digits after decimal point and after that you can write jargon values because ultimately an irrational number has a non terminating, non repeating decimal expansion.

Comment: @shraddheya - and what about periodic rationals?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: What we actually need here is that the _irrationals_ are dense (which, of course, they are).

Comment: @gottfried - SteamyRoot below in his answer has ensured that the decimal part is non repeating and not periodic. I was just suggesting that it is possible to always find such an irrational, if I would have succeeded in actually finding it(as SteamyRoot did), I wouldn't have commented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and you can explicitly construct such number. Suppose your rational number is
$$d = 0.d_1d_2d_3 \dots d_n$$
where $d_i \in \{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ stands for a digit .

Then $d$ is rational. Now take $d' = d + 10^{-n-1} \cdot \sqrt{2}$. This number has digits
$$d' = 0.d_1d_2d_3 \dots d_n 141421356 \dots$$
where the tail is just the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{2}$. Clearly $d'$ is irrational and $d$ and $d'$ have the same first $n$ digits after the decimal point.

You can do something similar for any rational and with any irrational, not just $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Would you please  have a look at it : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009311/finding-irrational-for-a-given-rational-number?noredirect=1#comment4125638_2009311

Answer (score 1):

Since the rationals are dense in the reals,
so are the rationals times
$\sqrt{2}$
(or any other irrational number),
and these numbers
are all irrational.

This does what is wanted.

Comment: OK. I looked at it.